# WLAPP file contents and versioning dependencies

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

Is there is way to extract and check the contents of WLAPP file. we just want to compare the wlapp files for older and new version of Apps, and see if the deployment of wlapp file is really required on wl console, if we already have the same version available over the console.

Thanks
djrecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but a .wlapp file is a regular .zip file.
You can change the extension from .wlapp to .zip and extract its contents.

Answer (score 0):

The command 'zipinfo' will help displaying the contents. 
zipinfo filename.wlapp

On an Unix or Linux machine, cksum command can be used to get the checksum.
If the checksum is same for those two versions, they can be considered same.
This method is not useful if you are sure that the one in hand is a re-built version but just that you are not sure if it has any changes.

I do not know about any other option.